# Deploying an AWS CodeStar project on a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

AWS CodeStar lets you spin up CodePipelines and CodeCommit repos to support your project. If I want to build a project in CodeStar and then take the resultant package, how can I deploy that package into another account?

For example, the basic "Python Web Service Lambda" CodeStar template generated these files,

```
$ ls ./ -R
./:
buildspec.yml  index.py  README.md  template.yml  tests

./tests:
test_handler.py
```

This notably lacks the templates for setting up the CodePipeline that deploys the code. Thus I am left to figure out how to deploy it myself.

How can I deploy the CodeStar templates onto a different AWS account?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Currently (2019-01-10)  The CodeStar functionality is limited. CodeStar Projects can only be created via the web console and can not be imported / exported /  codified. Sadly CodeStar is *only* a web console feature at this time.